# bash overrides the history even with histappend set to on

Tags: bash, shopt

I'm trying to write the bash history to a file (`...| 1 |...`), then change one character (`...| 2 |...`) in `HISTTIMEFORMAT` environment variable run couple commands and being able to see commands from the first run as well as commands from the second run.

Questions:

1. Why when I change the value it changes all the values before that in the same "column"?
2. Why `shopt -s histappend` doesn't make a difference?

OS:

```
[root@test ~]# cat /etc/*-release
CentOS release 6.10 (Final)
```

```
[root@test ~]# export HISTTIMEFORMAT='%a %h %d | %T | 1 |'; shopt -s histappend; echo 1; history 3
  872  Wed Jun 17 | 22:14:48 | 1 |export HISTTIMEFORMAT='%a %h %d | %T | 1 |'; shopt -s histappend; echo 1; history 3
  873  Wed Jun 17 | 22:14:50 | 1 |export HISTTIMEFORMAT='%a %h %d | %T | 1 |'; shopt -s histappend; echo 1; history 3
  874  Wed Jun 17 | 22:14:52 | 1 |export HISTTIMEFORMAT='%a %h %d | %T | 1 |'; shopt -s histappend; echo 1; history 3
[root@test ~]# export HISTTIMEFORMAT='%a %h %d | %T | 2 |'; shopt -s histappend; echo 2; history 3
  873  Wed Jun 17 | 22:14:50 | 2 |export HISTTIMEFORMAT='%a %h %d | %T | 1 |'; shopt -s histappend; echo 1; history 3
  874  Wed Jun 17 | 22:14:52 | 2 |export HISTTIMEFORMAT='%a %h %d | %T | 1 |'; shopt -s histappend; echo 1; history 3
  875  Wed Jun 17 | 22:15:02 | 2 |export HISTTIMEFORMAT='%a %h %d | %T | 2 |'; shopt -s histappend; echo 2; history 3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not looking at what is being stored in file. To do that you need something like:

```
tail -n 6 "$HISTFILE"
```

That will print 6 lines which correspond to 3 command lines stored in file.

```
$ export HISTTIMEFORMAT='%a %h %d | %T | 1 |'; shopt -s histappend; echo 1; history 3
   1
   15891  Wed Jun 17 | 20:18:27 | 1 |export HISTTIMEFORMAT='%a %h %d | %T | 1 |'; shopt -s histappend; echo 1; history 5
   15892  Wed Jun 17 | 20:18:41 | 1 |export HISTTIMEFORMAT='%a %h %d | %T | 1 |'; shopt -s histappend; echo 1; history 6
   15893  Wed Jun 17 | 20:18:44 | 1 |export HISTTIMEFORMAT='%a %h %d | %T | 1 |'; shopt -s histappend; echo 1; history 3

$ tail -n 6 "$HISTFILE"
   #1592439521
   export HISTTIMEFORMAT='%a %h %d | %T | 1 |'; shopt -s histappend; echo 1; history 6
   #1592439524
   export HISTTIMEFORMAT='%a %h %d | %T | 1 |'; shopt -s histappend; echo 1; history 3
   #1592439630
   tail -n 6 "$HISTFILE"
```

Assuming that the history file is being updated on each command executed.

Note that there is a comment line between each command actually stored.
That comment line actually store the Unix epoch in seconds when each command was executed. That value, for example: `1592439630` gets converted to the format that is being given via `TIMEFORMAT`. It is **one** simple number that gets converted to some other format. When you change the format, the same number gets converted to that different format. Therefore, there is no way to have some numbers converted with one format and others with some other format.

That `histappend` is set or not affects something quite different, not the format of values printed. It makes each command (without any format) to be appended to the history file but only when the shell exits or the command `history -w` is issued. In short, only if the history file is written to.

Comment: That makes sense, I guess I'm not using the right tool for the job. Actually my goal was to repllace `...| 1 |... ` with something like `$(logname)` to associate each command with the user. Do you have any suggestions on that?

Comment: or `$USER` `$SUDO_USER` instead of `logname`

Comment: You can store each command to a **different** file than history which records UID (user), real user, effective user (if needed), PID (shell instance on a computer) hostname (to differentiate several computers) but your best bet is to use the `rsyslog` server system. @Vor

Comment: @Vor Maybe something like: https://askubuntu.com/questions/93566/how-to-log-all-bash-commands-by-all-users-on-a-server#93570